# lambda select map difference in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Servernode is Rails Model Class.

I found something strange to me when I try to use lambda.

```
aaa = lambda {|node| node.available="Available"}
Servernode.select(&:aaa)
```

=> It can return array of ModelObject which meets the condition

But, when I try to

```
bbb = lambda {|node| node if node.available="Available"}
Servernode.map(&:bbb)
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for #<Class:0x000000067759b0>
```

The result is not what I expected and don't know why?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

This is because `select` is an `ActiveRecord::QueryObject` method. I think you've confused it with the `select` method for Ruby `Enumerable`. The `map` method is only available for `enumerables` as well.

Comment: Thanks for help. When I try to use
   ` Servernode.all.class.map {|node| node if node.status="Availalbe"}`
I got 
`NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for Servernode::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class`

But (**availible is a scope in Servernod model class**) 

   `Servernode.available.map {|node| node if node.status="Availalbe"}`

It can return an array.... really no ideas becuase I expect **Servernode.available is still not enumerable in this case**

Comment: It's because you just chained `map` after `class` on your 1st example. `ServerNode.all.class` will return a **class** object so you can't chain `map` to it. Try `ServerNode.all.map` it will do the trick.

For your 2nd example, when you executed `ServerNode.available`, you can chain `map` to it since when you call a `scope` method to a class, it returns an **ActiveRecord::Relation** which can be chained by a ruby `Enumerable` method.